# Install different VSTO Addins under same Custom Ribbon Tab

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I have developed a VSTO Addin in Visual Studio with C#. It is packaged into a MSI by using a Setup Project in VS.

When installed, it creates a Custom Ribbon Tab "Test" in Excel with a few Controls.

Now I want my similar second/third/... Addins to be installed under the same tab "Test".

If I just create a Custom Ribbon in, say, Addin2 named "Test", it just creates a second one when both Addins are installed, instead of displaying both controls under one tab.

Is there any control in VS that allows multiple Addins to share one Tab or is there a workaround for VSTO Addins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a button to a 3rd party ribbon tab addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787108/adding-a-button-to-a-3rd-party-ribbon-tab-addin)

Comment: That question is not the exact same, but the answer should work for you. Just put the idQ on the tab, not the group. I suspect you're using the Ribbon Designer right now, but you'll probably need to use Ribbon XML instead.

Comment: I concur with the answers from @Chris - that is the only way to share a custom tab. You add-in can always share the built-in Add-ins tab (or any other tab) with other Add-ins - indeed, there you have no choice in the matter..