# How to add a group to a (VBA) custom ribbon without xmlns/idQ?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ribbon, powerpoint

**Situation:**

- Users have an existing custom ribbon that is added via a .PPAM (combination of VBA macros and Ribbon customization XML).
- We want to add a group to that custom ribbon via our managed COM add-in
- For custom ribbons from other managed COM add-ins this is feasible via the xmlns:foo="bar" & idQ that can be extracted from the customUI [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052229/add-a-custom-ribbon-group-to-an-existing-custom-ribbon-group-in-word-2007)

**Complication:**

- Custom Ribbons from non-managed add-ins seem to have no xmlns namespace, they do not show up in the customUI
- Even via PowerPoint/Office the user can not customize those ribbons.

Any idea how we could achieve adding buttons?

We can request changes to the non-managed/VBA add-in.

Comment: Have you looked over this information, and tried the Custom UI Editor? http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: @rdhs Thanks, I looked at it, but didn't find anything for this problem in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VBA add-ins don't have their own namespace by default, but *can* have one.  If you create a custom namespace, then multiple VBA add-ins can share the same tab on the ribbon, for example.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
xmlns:nsMySpace="SomeName">
```

Then to create a new tab that other add-ins can share:

```
<tab idQ="nsMySpace:MySpace_Tab" label="MyTabLabel">
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Steve's answer we've discovered that VBA add-ins have a default namespace even when none is specified in their customUI.

You can extract the namespace by adding a control from the ribbon to the Quick Access and then exporting the UI Customizations. The resulting file should show:

```
<mso:cmd app="PowerPoint" dt="1" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Addin.ppam">
```

So the default namespace seems to be the complete Path to the add-in.

Comment: Ditto. Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

From a high perspective two add-ins can share a ribbon tab for controls because they are loaded into a single PowerPoint instance. When you develop a macro enabled file with a custom UI - only this file can be opened at the same time. But two add-ins can be run for the file/template. That's why idQ is intended to use by add-ins.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)